# build.gradle cannot detect environment variable

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a `./gradlew` script. Inside my `build.gradle`, I have a variable that takes value from the environment variable

```
def username = System.getenv('USERNAME')
print username
```

I've exported the environment variable by running `export USERNAME=someusername` before I run the `./gradlew` script

The result of `print username` is always `null`. I use both IntelliJ and VS Code and run the `./gradlew` script from the built-in zsh terminal.

Did I miss any setup? Previously before my Mac was formated, things go well. But after it was formatted, I just started to do Java again and install everything (JDK, IntelliJ). But suddenly I got this kind of result.

Comment: It works fine for me on Linux with Bash...

Comment: Your gradle code works. You're messing up the setup of your env var. Run the "export ..." command from the same shell from where you run the gradlew script. Or just run it in one go with `USERNAME=test ./gradlew ...`

Comment: Tried both by running the "export USERNAME=someusername" and also "USERNAME=someusername ./gradlew ..." in the same shell that I use to run the gradlew script. Still failing

Comment: @KevinDave have you ever found the solution for the problem?

Answer (score 6):

The environment is likely cached by the Gradle daemon. Force the daemon to stop with this command:

```
./gradlew --stop
```